# Issue - Eclipse Project test in android device

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, usb

How to setup the android device properly?

My new project in my android device -Samsung Galaxy Grand, but I couldn't. I have installed my device software so the device manager is clear. But when i get to the Running part from Android device chooser, under choose a running device, I get an android device there but the target is unknown, can't proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

because your app is build in higher version of android rather then your android device.
please check targetsdk in your manifest file of your project.

Comment: my app is created in 2.2 version(the first one) and my android version is 4.2.2

Comment: I have got a new problem now SDK is not even loading, can't able to create a new test project. Why

Comment: how to check the target SDK?

Comment: I found it myself. The Target SDK Version was empty, now i changed it to @string/hello. WHat to do now. Please somebody help. It still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

put this in your manifest file.

Comment: have you download sdk atleast android 4.1 and above?please check your sdk

Comment: I dont know how to check that. I in Android SDK Manager. THere are many SDKs here

Comment: I dont see 4.2.2 here to tick and download

Comment: Yeap Good, u got 4.3, I have no option to tick and download. Anyways my above question where did u study this???

Comment: please post this line  android:minSdkVersion="8" in your manifestfile.

Comment: After trying too many things now it now got a new error.  "failed to initialize monitor thread unable to establish loopback connection"

Comment: what text you are written in your manifest file for android:minSdkVersion?

Comment: in the AndroidManifest.xml Min=8, Max=nothing, Target=18

Comment: it is just a test project. Created and trying to check whether it is working in an emulator or android device. So no new codes given by me.